# Does Android HoneyComb support multiuser restricted account?

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb, multi-user, restrictions

a customer ordered us a tablet application, but they need a lot of access restriction to lock device functions such as:

1. Permit datas transfer only inside the application not outside
2. Restricted user access on the device (something close to admin and normal user permissions)
3. A framework/API that permit to create an internal mail reader/sender

Public API of iOS makes impossible to fulfill those requirements. I was wondering if Android makes life easier when there are those kind of restriction.

UPDATE: To make understand better the field of use. I'm talking about an application that "force" the device to be used just only with that application for an Enterprise use. The app is just like a CRM but the device should be blocked in some functions to make users only work with them and NOT playing or use facebook, market etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure you can achiev all of those, but you should look into the *device policy for android* [here](http://www.google.com/support/mobile/bin/answer.py?answer=190930&&hl=en) and [here](http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?answer=1056433).

1) Not sure what you mean by point 1. If you mean controlling all data transfer from the device, you might be a in a bind considering the only way to get a firewall running on android is by rooting the device. Perhaps you could look into writing a custom launcher/home like [KidZone](http://www.appbrain.com/app/kidzone-secure-home-launcher/com.deemo.kidzone.main) that only shows approved apps? - Not nearly as secure, though.

2) Honeycomb, so far, doesn't have multi-user support - though you can have multiple google accounts registered. The custom launcher could help in this regard though.

3) I don't see the point of doing this unless they already have a custom mail infrastructure in place. Otherwise just go with exchange.

Comment: Hi Mus, thank you for the explanation. In point 1 I'm meaning that our customer doesn't want that the user could access Internet or any kind of connection type except inside the application. It seems weird, but the device should be given to the sales force of this company and they want that this could be used just for work. I will update the question to make that clear. THX andrea

Comment: I guess that you've found the solution with KidZone ;-)

Answer (score 0):

> Permit datas transfer only inside the application not outside

Do not request the `INTERNET` permission.

> Restricted user access on the device (something close to admin and normal user permissions)

You would have to implement this yourself.

> A framework/API that permit to create an internal mail reader/sender

I have no idea what this means.

Comment: Hi CommonsWare, thanks. In the point 3 I mean do not use the default email app, but build one inside the application. In iOS there is the MessageUI.framework that allow you to send email from within an application but not to receive them, maybe Android has.

Comment: `javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage` should be alright for sending email from your app.

Comment: @Andrea @Mus: JavaMail is not part of Android. There is a port of it for Android floating around, though. Bear in mind, though, that sending mail means you need the `INTERNET` permission, which runs afoul of your "permit datas transfer only inside the application not outside". Either you are communicating on the Internet, or you are not.